# Is $P(ab \mid a)$ the same as $P(b)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Essentially what the question title says, $ab$ is just usual multiplication.

Is $P(ab \mid a) = P(b)$? This intuitively seems true to me since if we fix $a$ then the product $ab$ strictly depends on what $b$ turns out to be, i. e., $P(b)$?

**Edit**:

Consider two 10 faced die where faces are $F = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$. Let's say a pair of die are rolled one after another and the first one comes out $a \in F$. What is the probability that once the second is also rolled, the product of the two faces is $ab$ given the first roll was $a$. This is to say $P(ab \mid a)$. If I am right then,
$$
P(ab \mid a) = P(a \mid a) \cdot P(b \mid a) = P(b \mid a) = P(b)
$$
The last equality is due to statistical independence.

Comment: The question does not seem to make much sense. Would you care to clarify and/or share the source of this question?

Comment: What does $P(ab|a)$ mean?  What does $P(b)$ mean?  Not sure it's relevant, but for a continuous distribution, the probability of getting a particular value is $0$.

Comment: The inputs for a probability are sets, not numbers

Comment: Oh yeah okay I see, well, let's say $a \in S \ni b$ where $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ and $|S| = 10$. The source of the problem is another bigger problem I am trying to solve and this will help me in a simplification. I'll edit the question once I get a second.

Comment: Okay, I edited the question to include an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to generalize your example, suppose you have two independent discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$.  You want to know if $\mathbb P(XY = xy \mid X = x) = \mathbb P(Y = y)$ for all possible values $x$ of $X$ and $y$ of $Y$.

That is indeed true **if** $X$ can't take the value $0$.  But if $X = 0$, $XY = 0$ no matter what $Y$ is, so $\mathbb P(XY = 0\cdot y \mid X = 0) = 1 \ne \mathbb P(Y = y)$.

Comment: Is my reasoning with $P(ab \mid a) = P(a \mid a)P(b \mid a)$ correct? Or did I just reach the right conclusion with the wrong steps?

Comment: First of all, your notation $P(ab \mid a)$ etc is terrible: you have to specify what events you are dealing with, not just the numbers.  I don't know where you're getting $P(ab \mid a) = P(a \mid a) P(b \mid a)$.

Comment: It is not really my notation, people don't always seem to [make the notation clear enough](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2211829/783364), I am just trying to understand.